# Does a transaction rollback in AWS Aurora Mysql affect data entered at the same time in the DB from other sources?

Tags: mysql, transactions, amazon-aurora

I am trying to execute a script containing SQL statements encapsulated in a transaction. If any of the statements fail, the transaction rolls back. The DB on which the transaction runs is prod DB. So does it mean that the data coming from customers into the db will also be removed for the time duration when the transaction was active ?

-Thanks,
Vinit

Answer (score 0):

No, the transaction is isolated to only calls relating to it. Other calls will be run separated from it.

Amazon Aurora is compliant to the AC**I**D principles. For example, this is an description of the I(isolation) in ACID:

> Isolation - when multiple users are reading and writing from the same
> table all at once, isolation of their transactions ensures that the
> concurrent transactions don’t interfere with or affect one another.
> Each request can occur as though they were occurring one by one, even
> though they're actually occurring simultaneously.

Quoted from [here](https://www.databricks.com/glossary/acid-transactions)

I recommend you to read up on ACID principles, for example here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID